# trigger to compare a new entry with previous entries from a column in sql

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

im trying to build an app on apex oracle for a school project, but first i need some functionalities. one of them is a trigger. i want to compare a new entry with previous entries from a column from a table. if the entry is there, will display an error. here is what i got so far:

```
create or replace TRIGGER client_check 
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON ORDERS
    for each row
    DECLARE
    new_client number;
    BEGIN
    new_client :=0;
    select CLIENT_ID into new_client from ORDERS where CLIENT_ID = :new.CLIENT_ID;
    if new_client (condition to check if its already there)
        Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Client already ordered!');
    end if;
    END;
```

i dont know how to write it. Thank you.

Comment: You do not need a trigger. Simply add a unique constraint on CLIENT_ID column

Comment: Use only ONE tag for the DB that you actually use, as trigger syntax differs across database types, and to ensure that an answer is useful to the DB that you have.

Comment: Maybe your clients wont be happy if they can only order once?

Comment: What is the assignment ? Is it "create at least one trigger" or is it "a client can only order once" ? Because what you are trying cannot / should never be done with a trigger.

Comment: the assignment is 3. Add a trigger to the Orders table to confirm that the customer has not already ordered a taxi. The
customer is allowed to order only one taxi.
So yeah, it requires a trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you simply need a count function to count the no of orders -

```
create or replace TRIGGER client_check 
BEFORE INSERT
ON ORDERS
for each row
DECLARE
new_client number := 0;
BEGIN

select COUNT(CLIENT_ID)
  into new_client
  from ORDERS
 where CLIENT_ID = :new.CLIENT_ID;

if new_client > 0
    Raise_Application_Error(-20000, 'Client already ordered!');
end if;
END;
```